# Python Pyforms : how to use css in Pyforms or html-api in pyforms

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyforms

I am using Pyforms for generating forms. But, I have to use stylesheet/css/html-api in my pyforms. I also follow step which have been given on this [link](http://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/style-layout/). I want to know how to add css and making my layout beautiful. Can you please give me a better solution for that

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the PyForms version 3.0, you can do this:

1. Import the settings

   ```
   from pyforms import settings as formSettings
   ```
2. Modify the PYFORMS_STYLESHEET variable

   ```
   formSettings.PYFORMS_STYLESHEET = cssFilePath
   ```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Youu can add a css stylesheet by importing `settings` and adding a `settings.py` file where you reference the css file.

```
from pysettings import conf
import settings
conf+=settings
```

---

**settings.py**

```
PYFORMS_STYLESHEET = "stylesheet.css"
```

---

See [the accompany tutorial](https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms/blob/master/tutorials/3.CodeOrganization/PersonWindow.py).